# Java: generic filter map function

Tags: java, filter, dictionary, clone

I'm trying to develop a generic function to filter maps.

The code I have so far is:

```
public static Map<?, ?> filterAttrs(Map<?, ?> args, String... unless) {

    Map<?, ?> filteredAttrs = Map.class.newInstance();

    Arrays.sort(unless);
    for (Object o : args.keySet()) {
        if (Arrays.binarySearch(unless, o.toString()) < 0 ) {
            filteredAttrs.put(o, args.get(o));
        }
    }
    return filteredAttrs;
}
```

I get the following errors in filteredAttrs.put

> The method put(capture#5-of ?, capture#6-of ?) in the type Map is not applicable for the arguments (Object, capture#8-of ?)

I don't know how to instantiate a generic `Map` (I tried with 1Map.class.newInstance()`).

Any ideas?

Edit: after reading many answers, the problem seems to be how to make `filteredAttrs` be an instance of the same type as `args`. `(Map) args.getClass().newInstance()` seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with this code is that the type system prevents you from putting an object into a `Map` whose key type is `?`.  This is because if the key type is `?`, the compiler has no idea what's actually being stored in the map - it could be `Object`, or `Integer`, or `List<Object>` - and so it can't confirm that what you're trying to add to the map is actually of the correct type and won't be out of place in the `Map`.  As an example, if you have this method:

```
public static void breakMyMap(Map<?, ?> m) {
    m.put(new Object(), new Object()); // Won't compile
}
```

and then write code like this:

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
breakMyMap(myMap);
```

Then if the code in `breakMyMap` were to compile, it would put a pair of `Object`s as keys and values into a `Map<String, String>`, breaking the invariant that all the elements are indeed `String`s.

To fix this, instead of making this function work on `Map<?, ?>`, change the function so that you have more type information about what the keys and values are.  For example, you could try this:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> filterAttrs(Map<K, V> args, String... unless) {

    Map<K, V> filteredAttrs = new HashMap<K, V>();

    Arrays.sort(unless);
    for (K o : args.keySet()) {
        String attr = o.toString();
        if (Arrays.binarySearch(unless, o.toString()) < 0 ) {
            filteredAttrs.put(o, args.get(o));
        }
    }
    return filteredAttrs;
}
```

Now that the compiler knows that the key type is `K`, it can verify that the `put` will not mix up the types of the keys in the map.

Another thing I should point out is that the code you had would never have worked even if this did compile.  The reason is that the line

```
Map<?, ?> filteredAttrs = Map.class.newInstance();
```

Will cause an exception at runtime because `Map` is an *interface*, not a class, and so trying to use `newInstance` to create an instance of it will fail to work correctly.  To fix this, you can either specify the type of the map explicitly (as I've done in the above code), or get the class of the argument:

```
Map<K, V> filteredAttrs = args.getClass().newInstance();
```

Of course, this isn't guaranteed to work either, though the general contract for collections is that all collections *should* have a no-arg constructor.

Hope this helps!

Comment: great answer! I was beginning to try with generics, but I couldn't find a way to instantiate a generic map. the (Map) args.getClass().newInstance() seems to do the trick

Comment: If I understand correctly, this code determines at runtime how to instantiate filteredAttrs, and then cast it to a Map. The compiler hast enough information to know filteredAttrs type at compile time (that is, the same type as args) Is there no way to tell it so???

Comment: @opensas- You're correct, the cast isn't necessary.  I just removed it.  I haven't used `newInstance` since pre-1.5, so I didn't know that it actually had the right type info at runtime.  Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 5):

I consider it to be bad if people are reinventing the wheel (and not doing any better).

To fix all your problems in a single suggestion: Can you try [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)?

For example then you could use [Maps](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html):

- Maps.filterEntries
- Maps.filterKeys
- Maps.filterValues

Or at least write a filter that takes predicate as argument.

Answer (score 3):

This line

```
Map<?, ?> filteredAttrs = Map.class.newInstance();
```

should throw an InstantiationException - because `Map` is an interface - unless you've implemented your own class named `Map`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot put anything into a `Map<?, ?>`, because the compiler doesn't know exactly what kind of map it is. In the line:

```
filteredAttrs.put(o, args.get(o));
```

you are pretending that the `Map<?, ?>` is a `Map<Object, Object>`, but that's not what it is. Angelika Langer's Java Generics FAQ explains [why this doesn't work](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ304) in more detail.

You should add type parameters to the method; then it's also not necessary to create the new map via reflection:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> filterAttrs(Map<K, V> args, String... unless) {
    Map<K, V> filteredAttrs = new HashMap<K, V>();

    Arrays.sort(unless);
    for (K o : args.keySet()) {
        if (Arrays.binarySearch(unless, o.toString()) < 0) {
            filteredAttrs.put(o, args.get(o));
        }
    }
    return filteredAttrs;
}
```

Comment: I want filteredAttrs to be of the same type as args (HaspMap, LinkedHashMap, whatever) is it ok to just instantiate a new HashMap??? How can I tell the compiler to do so?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot instantiate Map because it is an interface. Don't use `?` because it causes confusion to begin with.

```
public static <T, K> Map<T, K> filterAttrs(Map<T, K> args, T... unless) {
    Map<T, K> filteredAttrs;

    filteredAttrs = new HashMap<T, K>();
    Arrays.sort(unless);
    for (T o : args.keySet()) {
        if (Arrays.binarySearch(unless, o) < 0) {
            filteredAttrs.put(o, args.get(o));
        }
    }

    return filteredAttrs;
}
```

You have this line that does nothing, so I removed it:-

```
String attr = o.toString();
```

Comment: Yeap, with this cropded down example that line is useless, I'll remove it from the question, thanks...